# How to trigger HTTP PUT request without Ajax?

Tags: http

Regarding to a static link on a web page, the browser will issue GET or POST request to the web site, depending on whether a form of parameters attached.

However, I want the browser to issue a PUT request for that link, how can I do that? I know that Ajax could do it, but I don't want to use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the browser to issue a PUT request for that link

it seems that `PUT` and `DELETE` are currently unsupported in html forms, according to [this submission to the w3](http://amundsen.com/examples/put-delete-forms/).

> I know that Ajax could do it

Not always true. Because `PUT` and `DELETE` are at times [unsupported by some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers), ajax cannot consume them without making a dummy param to trigger a real `PUT` or `DELETE` server side, which gives the illusion of full HTTP support by ajax.